# Delete DB table rows in which a PK is used as a FK Constraint

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a method that deletes a user from my Users table by userId:

```
public void DeleteUser(int id)
{
    User delObj = (Users.Where(u => u.UserId == id)).Single();
    Users.Remove(delObj);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

The primary key userId is also used as a foreign key in a userroles table where there is a UserRoleId (PK), UserId (FK), and RoleId (FK). I am unsure how to knock out both rows in both tables with one method.

Here are the exact properties:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}



public class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public short RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

I add this into my DbContext and its still not working:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.UserRoles)
        .WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

A foreign constraint error still occurs.

Comment: are you trying to delete User or UserRoles??

Comment: I'm trying to delete a User and their Role that is held in user role

Comment: you need to delete the UserRoles associated with that user first and then delete the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure UserRole entity instead:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding this before deleting the userobject:

```
UserRole deleteUserRoleObject = (UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == id)).Single();
        UserRoles.Remove(deleteUserRoleObject);
        SaveChanges();
```